# Posting Multiple Entries to a MySQL Table via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a jobs table in our MySQL database that contains the following fields:
OpenJobID int(11)
JobID int(11)
RestuarantID int(11)
DateOpened
DateFilled

There are 4 JobIDs stored in a separate table with descriptions.

In my web application, after the user selects the appropriate restaurant via dropdown box, I want to provide a checkbox for each of the for JobIDs.  The user would select 1-4 jobs to post and press the submit button.

Is it possible to "bulk" insert up to 4 entries in my jobs table based on the number of checkboxes selected?  Should I set an array for the 4 checkboxes and create nested if..then statements where if checkbox1.value=true then insert blah into jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question you will need:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='jobs[]' id='job1' />
```

and this will produce one array in PHP

Comment: Do I then create the array in PHP to return the list of jobs and a separate array that inserts the selected jobs into the openjobs table?

Comment: $_POST['jobs'] will have only the selected checkboxes.